# display album folder as a stack or deck android

Tags: android, android-layout, html, android-image, categorization

I want to categorize the images on my device and display it in different albums where the albums look like a stack or deck of images. This is quite a common feature in the default gallery, or applications like QuickPic etc.

How is this achieved? Is it a straightforward effort?
What is the estimated time reqiured for this effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the images from the device and put them into different folders. Your app logic would recognize each folder as an album. Then a layout would be created which would display each album with the top 3 or 5 random images in it as a deck of cards (use a relative layout for this to place images on top of one another and use can use a transform function to rotate them slightly if you want also). For each album you would have one deck of cards,and when the user selects an album, you would launch another activity which would be your custom android gallery for displaying the images in a particular album. Here's a good tutorial for how to build one of these custom galleries:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery/

As for the time requirement, it's really depends on your skill level. It can range from about a week to 2 months or more I suppose. It isn't very hard to do once you get the hang of the basics of the android file system, a bit of graphics and manipulating the gallery.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks a lot! :) The link looks very helpful!